# Бесконечное обновление страницы

Tags: javascript

Хотел, чтобы страница один раз обновлялась через 1 секунду и все,
а у меня через 1 секунду начинает происходить бесконечное обновление.
Как устранить бесконечное обновление страницы?

```js
function sayHi() {
 document.location.reload();
  return false;
}
setTimeout(sayHi, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="timer">
БЕСКОНЕЧНОЕ ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ СТРАНИЦЫ
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function sayHi() {
    document.location.reload();
    return false;
}
if(localStorage.getItem("permission_to_update") == ""){
    localStorage.setItem("permission_to_update", "no");
    setTimeout(sayHi, 1000);
}else{localStorage.setItem("permission_to_update", "")};
```

Comment: Воо спасибо вам за все =)

Comment: @Black_Viper что за поколение копипастеров растёт.. Ужс.

Comment: Так вы сказали про половину дела, вы ничего не говорили про getItem и setItem. Поэтому я ничего и не понял.

Comment: @Black_Viper Я указал док. В доках всё написано. Вы просто лентяй

Comment: Так в доках все сыро написано ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Внутри функции надо сделать следующее:

1. Сделать `if`
2. Условие должно проверять есть ли значение по определённому ключу в `localstorage`.
3. Если нет - записать любое значение с любым ключом. И перезагружать страницу
4. Если есть что-то по заданному ключау - сразу выход из функции

`localstorage` - как куки, хранилище в браузере, в котором можно хранить данные, записывать туда и считывать

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Ничего не понял, что за ключ? Прочитал статью там все сыро и непонятно =( Мне бы помог пример кода

Comment: ключ, который вы сами положите туда, если его там нет